# Hyperledger Fabric issues and doubts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I tried to reach out on fabric rocket chat but didnt get much help there hence posting it on SO.
I have following doubts:

1. Can we access block height within the chaincode(i know it is feasible from the client but is it possible within chaincode)
2. Can we invoke a new transaction from an ongoing transaction with in the chaincode?
3. Would like to know where is the history of data stored in hyperledger fabric
4. Can we query based on transactionid with in the chaincode?
5. Is there any feasibility of writing scheduler inside fabric chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

2. Can you explain a little on this.
3. You can check the chaincodes, ledgersData, transientStore etc by logging into the peers by `docker  exec -it <peer id> bash` and then `cd /var/hyperledger/production/`
4. Yes you can, it depends on how you are storing the state. You can store the state as `putStringState(java.lang.String key, java.lang.String value)` where key can be transaction id. and then query it later using `getStringState(java.lang.String key)`.
   (method names as per java chaincode)

Comment: #2 -> in general we invoke a `transaction` from client, but in my case i want an ongoing transaction to trigger a `new transaction`

Comment: #3 -> is there a way to access this history in the chaincode?

Comment: #4 -> that requires changes in the `key, value` pair been saved, that basically means nothing is implicitly available to query on `transactionId`. Your solution is more of saving `txId` as a key or value

Comment: 2. i think you are talking about transaction proposal. transaction proposal can be only sent by an application client to specific endorsing peers.

Comment: @Harshit putStringState(java.lang.String key, java.lang.String value) stores the value as a byte[] . If an object is stored as a value it cannot be deserialized again. Any suggestion how could we retrieve the state of the Object stored against the key?